Flutter - Barcode Scanning not registering input correctly on android but is on PC
I have a barcode scanner that I have connected to a tablet. When scanning barcodes it doesn't register some of the text input.
For example: Z293501924293 is scanned, but the text field will only show some of the text. Sometimes it misses text in the middle and sometimes it misses two characters at the end. Sometimes itcaptures the input correctly.
It does seem fine scanning on PC though.
void lookupSKU() async {
    final enteredText = skuController.text;
    print("lookupSKU triggered with: $enteredText"); // Logging the input
    
    bool success = await logic.lookupSKU(enteredText);
    if (success) {
      setState(() {});
      skuController.clear();
      skuFocusNode.requestFocus();
    } else {
      CustomSnackBar.show(context, 'Invalid identifier format.');
    }
  }



SizedBox(
                  width: 600,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          autocorrect: false,
                          autofocus: true,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: skuController,
                          focusNode: skuFocusNode,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Enter SKU',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          //onSubmitted: (value) => lookupSKU(),  // Trigger lookup only on enter
                          onSubmitted: (value) {
                            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {
                              lookupSKU();
                            });
                          },
                        
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 8),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: lookupSKU,
                        child: const Text('Lookup'),
                      ),
  

I've tried setting onChange listener delays and onSubmit delays, not sure what else to do.
I finally got something working it seems. Instead of directly inputting text into the textfield, I had to capture keyboard input and it seems to be working now.

void lookupSKU() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 800)); // Slight delay before processing
    final enteredText = skuController.text;
    print("lookupSKU triggered with: $enteredText"); // Logging the input
    
    bool success = await logic.lookupSKU(enteredText);
    if (success) {
      setState(() {});
      skuController.clear();
      skuFocusNode.requestFocus();
    } else {
      CustomSnackBar.show(context, 'Invalid identifier format.');
    }
  }

  KeyEventResult _handleKeyEvent(FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
      final String key = event.character ?? '';
      if (key == '\n') {  // '\n' corresponds to the Enter key
        lookupSKU();
        _bufferedInput = "";
        skuFocusNode.requestFocus();
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      } else if (key.isNotEmpty && key.length == 1) {
        _bufferedInput += key;
        skuController.text = _bufferedInput; // Update the text field with buffered input
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }
    }
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }

Expanded(
                        child: Focus(
                          focusNode: skuFocusNode,
                          onKeyEvent: _handleKeyEvent,
                          child: TextField(
                            autocorrect: false,
                            autofocus: true,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            controller: skuController,
                            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none, // Ensure no auto-capitalization
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Enter SKU',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ),




Marking as solved. Added to my post for how I solved it
